# curses.getstr with pre-populated value

Tags: python, curses

Having some issues with Python `curses`'s `getstr`.

First, left arrow behaves as delete. How can I set it simply to act as left?

Second, I want the `getstr` to be pre-populated with some default value. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advace!

Comment: That's two questions, with the same answer: you'd write your own `getstr`.  A tutorial would help, but that's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using a Textbox instead of getstr. When setting a Textbox to a single line, it accepts the ENTER key for submission. Here is my solution which displays a centered single line input field, which prepopulates the input value and uses the arrow keys to move around.

```
def get_string(current_value="", title="Value"):
    # Calculate the dimensions to center the new window
    rows = curses.LINES
    cols = curses.COLS
    prompt_window_height = 3
    prompt_window_width = int(cols / 3)
    prompt_window_y = int(rows / 2) - int(prompt_window_height / 2)
    prompt_window_x = int(cols / 2) - int(prompt_window_width / 2)

    # Create the window to show the surrounding border
    prompt_window_border = curses.newwin(prompt_window_height, prompt_window_width, prompt_window_y, prompt_window_x)
    prompt_window_border.box()
    prompt_window_border.addstr(0, 1, " " + title + " ")
    prompt_window_border.refresh()

    # Create the innder window to accept user input
    curses.curs_set(1)
    prompt_window_input = curses.newwin(prompt_window_height - 2, prompt_window_width -2, prompt_window_y + 1, prompt_window_x + 1)
    prompt_window_input.addstr(str(current_value))
    prompt_window_text_box = Textbox(prompt_window_input, insert_mode=True)
    prompt_window_text_box.edit()
    user_input = prompt_window_text_box.gather().strip()
    curses.curs_set(0)

    return user_input
```